# Microsoft Spy++

Tags: winapi, microsoft-spy++

Как работать с MS Spy++? Делаю все "по - инструкции", выбираю окно, сообщения..но Spy не выводит ни единого сообщения, лог постоянно чист. Или выдаётся то, что на скриншоте. В чём беда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не та битность?

Comment: @VladD оказалось веселее. Не было прав доступа к программе Spy

Comment: Ого! Странно, что она вообще запустилась.

Comment: @VladD с трудом локализировал эту проблему..с таким еще не встречался)